# Woocommerce delivery in 1-3 days option

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to make a new webstore using Woocommerce. It gives me only the options in stock or not in stock but i want to have like a option in stock 1-3 days is there a way to do this because i didnt found one.
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe custom stock statuses are possible yet. It seems to be under consideration so [lend your voice](https://trello.com/c/JuJugV5Y). This is the 2nd question I've seen regarding it in a month so it seems to be needed.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer i voted for it seems like more people like to have it.

Comment: I'm sure it is tricky, because most of the code is geared towards keeping track of the actual number of items in stock. You can enable back orders and make a note about how many days it might take for the back order to be fulfilled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912556/add-stock-option-in-woocommerce this is what im using now it gives me now 4 options out of stock, in stock, 1-3 days and 3-5 days