# Add a stock option to Woocommerce 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add in a custom stock_status to woocommerce 3.0 in wordpress.

The end goal is to add a 3rd inventory option on the product edit page, "On Hold", and display that stock status on the product page.

Previously I was able to use the method here:
[Add stock option in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912556/add-stock-option-in-woocommerce), which does work to add extra stock options to the product admin, but it looks like with Woocommerce 3.0 there is something over-riding my settings on the actual product page. It was also working on the products page until I upgraded to 3.0.

My functions.php:

```
function add_custom_stock_type() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('._stock_status_field').not('.custom-stock-status').remove();
});
</script>
<?php   

woocommerce_wp_select( array( 'id' => '_stock_status', 'wrapper_class' => 'hide_if_variable custom-stock-status', 'label' => __( 'Stock status', 'woocommerce' ), 'options' => array(
    'instock' => __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ),
    'outofstock' => __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ),
    'onhold' => __( 'On Hold', 'woocommerce' ), // The new option !!!
), 'desc_tip' => true, 'description' => __( 'Controls whether or not the product is listed as "in stock" or "out of stock" on the frontend.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_stock_status', 'add_custom_stock_type');

function save_custom_stock_status( $product_id ) {
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', wc_clean( $_POST['_stock_status'] ) );
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_stock_status',99,1);

function woocommerce_get_custom_availability( $data, $product ) {
switch( $product->get_stock_status ) {
    case 'onhold':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'On Hold', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'on-hold' );
    break;
    case 'instock':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'in-stock' );
    break;
    case 'outofstock':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'out-of-stock' );
    break;
}
return $data;
}
add_action('woocommerce_get_availability', 'woocommerce_get_custom_availability', 3, 2);
```

https://pastebin.com/EFtBVY9h

I can see in the DB that the stock_status is properly setting to "On Hold", my custom status, when I select it on the admin, but this is not being applied on the actual products page.

To verify, I modified my price.php to simply output the stock status:

```
<p class="price">

<?php 
    $stockamount = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $price = $product->get_price_html();
    $stockstatus = $product->get_stock_status();
    $pricelabelone = "Out of Stock";
    $pricelabeltwo = "On Hold";

     echo $stockstatus;            
?>
</p>
```

However, even though I set products to "On Hold" (and this is saving), the product page is always outputting "In Stock" (test product:
http://aegis-staging.byethost7.com/dgh/product/santa-cruz-h13-custom-42-cocobolo-and-moon-spruce/).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution may help you to solve your problem. Use **"get_post_meta()"** instead of using **get_stock_status()** to get stock status.

Go through the **"woocommerce_get_availability"** hook code like the below code

```
function woocommerce_get_custom_availability( $data, $product ) {
$stock_status = get_post_meta($product->id , '_stock_status' , true );
switch( $stock_status  ) {
    case 'onhold':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'On Hold', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'on-hold' );
    break;
    case 'instock':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'in-stock' );
    break;
    case 'outofstock':
        $data = array( 'availability' => __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' ), 'class' => 'out-of-stock' );
    break;
}
return $data;
}
add_action('woocommerce_get_availability', 'woocommerce_get_custom_availability', 3, 2);
```